# Unable to fix fill issue

Tags: pine-script

Error: Cannot call `fill` with arguments (series, series, color); available overloads: fill(hline, hline, series__color, float, literal__string, literal__bool, string) => void; fill(plot, plot, series__color, float, literal__string, literal__bool, string) => void

```
//@version4
study(title="Zone", shorttitle="", overlay=true) 
wid = input(title="Width", type=integer, defval = 1)
sup = green
res = red
hl = black
piv = blue

open1 = security(tickerid, 'D', open) 

r1 = security(tickerid, 'D', (high[1] - low[1])) 
r2 = security(tickerid, 'D', (high[2] - low[2])) 
r3 = security(tickerid, 'D', (high[3] - low[3]))
r4 = security(tickerid, 'D', (high[4] - low[4]))
r5 = security(tickerid, 'D', (high[5] - low[5]))
r6 = security(tickerid, 'D', (high[6] - low[6]))
r7 = security(tickerid, 'D', (high[7] - low[7])) 
r8 = security(tickerid, 'D', (high[8] - low[8])) 
r9 = security(tickerid, 'D', (high[9] - low[9]))
r10 = security(tickerid, 'D', (high[10] - low[10]))

dhnav_10 = ((((r1+r2+r3+r4+r5+r6+r7+r8+r9+r10) /10)/2) + open1)
dhnav_9 = ((((r1+r2+r3+r4+r5+r6+r7+r8+r9) /9)/2) + open1)
dhnav_8 = ((((r1+r2+r3+r4+r5+r6+r7+r8) /8)/2) + open1)
dhnav_7 = ((((r1+r2+r3+r4+r5+r6+r7) /7)/2) + open1)
dhnav_6 = ((((r1+r2+r3+r4+r5+r6) /6)/2) + open1)
dhnav_5 = ((((r1+r2+r3+r4+r5) /5)/2) + open1)
dhnav_4 = ((((r1+r2+r3+r4) /4)/2) + open1)
dhnav_3 = ((((r1+r2+r3) /3)/2) + open1)
dhnav_2 = ((((r1+r2) /2)/2) + open1)
dhnav_1 = ((((r1) /1)/2) + open1)

dhmax = max(dhnav_4, max(dhnav_3, dhnav_2))
dhmin = min(dhnav_4, max(dhnav_3, dhnav_2))

dhmax1 = max(dhmax, max(dhnav_5, dhnav_6))
dhmin1 = min(dhmin, max(dhnav_5, dhnav_6))

dhmax2 = max(dhmax1, max(dhnav_7, dhnav_8))
dhmin2 = min(dhmin1, max(dhnav_7, dhnav_8))

dhmax3 = max(dhmax2, max(dhnav_9, dhnav_10))
dhmin3 = min(dhmin2, max(dhnav_9, dhnav_10))

dhmax4 = max(dhmax3, dhnav_1)
dhmin4 = min(dhmin3, dhnav_1)

plot(dhmax4, title="Resistance", color=res, linewidth = wid)
plot(dhmin4, title="Resistance", color=res, linewidth = wid)

fill(dhmax4,dhmin4,color=lime)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the 3rd time you've asked this question.
It has already been explained in your previous (now deleted) questions.
Please refrain from asking again.

This is the solution to your problem:

```
//@version=4
study(title="Zone", shorttitle="", overlay=true) 
wid = input(title="Width", type=input.integer, defval = 1)
sup = color.green
res = color.red
hl = color.black
piv = color.blue

open1 = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', open)

r1 = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', (high[1] - low[1])) 
r2 = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', (high[2] - low[2])) 
r3 = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', (high[3] - low[3]))
r4 = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', (high[4] - low[4]))
r5 = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', (high[5] - low[5]))
r6 = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', (high[6] - low[6]))
r7 = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', (high[7] - low[7])) 
r8 = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', (high[8] - low[8])) 
r9 = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', (high[9] - low[9]))
r10 = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', (high[10] - low[10]))

dhnav_10 = ((((r1+r2+r3+r4+r5+r6+r7+r8+r9+r10) /10)/2) + open1)
dhnav_9 = ((((r1+r2+r3+r4+r5+r6+r7+r8+r9) /9)/2) + open1)
dhnav_8 = ((((r1+r2+r3+r4+r5+r6+r7+r8) /8)/2) + open1)
dhnav_7 = ((((r1+r2+r3+r4+r5+r6+r7) /7)/2) + open1)
dhnav_6 = ((((r1+r2+r3+r4+r5+r6) /6)/2) + open1)
dhnav_5 = ((((r1+r2+r3+r4+r5) /5)/2) + open1)
dhnav_4 = ((((r1+r2+r3+r4) /4)/2) + open1)
dhnav_3 = ((((r1+r2+r3) /3)/2) + open1)
dhnav_2 = ((((r1+r2) /2)/2) + open1)
dhnav_1 = ((((r1) /1)/2) + open1)
 
dhmax = max(dhnav_4, max(dhnav_3, dhnav_2))
dhmin = min(dhnav_4, max(dhnav_3, dhnav_2))

dhmax1 = max(dhmax, max(dhnav_5, dhnav_6))
dhmin1 = min(dhmin, max(dhnav_5, dhnav_6))

dhmax2 = max(dhmax1, max(dhnav_7, dhnav_8))
dhmin2 = min(dhmin1, max(dhnav_7, dhnav_8))

dhmax3 = max(dhmax2, max(dhnav_9, dhnav_10))
dhmin3 = min(dhmin2, max(dhnav_9, dhnav_10))

dhmax4 = max(dhmax3, dhnav_1)
dhmin4 = min(dhmin3, dhnav_1)

p1 = plot(dhmax4, title="Resistance", color=res, linewidth = wid)
p2 = plot(dhmin4, title="Resistance", color=res, linewidth = wid)

fill(p1, p2, color=color.lime)
```